Sorting user-defined array with strings gives wrong order, even when file content is fully available on disk
I am querying ElasticSearch and sorting the documents locally in Bash with jq, as sorting in ES is too slow for me.
The original purpose is to create a CSV file.
But I find the sorting does not work properly, it seems sort step does nothing.
As I am launching cURL requests, I thought the wrong order is due to content is chunked so I save some results into a local test.json file and tried again, but it still does not work.
test.json:
{
    "took": 680,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 1,
        "successful": 1,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "max_score": 1.0,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "my-index",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "111111113584925",
                "_score": 1.0,
                "fields": {
                    "field2": [
                        "FOO"
                    ],
                    "field1": [
                        "111111113584925"
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "my-index",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "111111121254059",
                "_score": 1.0,
                "fields": {
                    "field2": [
                        "FOO"
                    ],
                    "field1": [
                        "111111121254059"
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}

(There are many more records - edited for brevity.)
Command that I use:
jq '.hits.hits[].fields | [.field1[0] + "," + .field2[0]] | sort | .[0]' -r test.json

The result:
111111113584925,FOO
111111121254059,FOO
111111116879444,FOO

etc.
Why?
Should I rely on jq sorting? Am I using it correctly? I mean I want to do string comparison by alphabetical order, and field1 all have unique values, so it will never be a tie and start to compare values of field2(it also could have various values but I only want to sort by field1)
Should I use Bash sort -k 1 instead? Which is faster when it comes to 100K rows?

If you look at your intermediate results, you'll see that after your first step, you have separate objects, and no longer an array as the top-level element. The sort then applies to each element separately. The answers you received make sure you actually have an array before sorting.

See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/613779/how-to-sort-a-stream-of-json-objects-by-field-value-using-jq

Why do you wrap a single element in an array, sort, then unwrap the array element again?

sort works on an array as input. Your arrays have only a single element, so there's nothing to be sorted. You don't pass 1 large array of arrays to sort, but lots of single-element arrays.

I'm not that familiar with sorting in jq, but looks to me like it would be just as easy to use jq '.hits.hits[].fields | .field1[0] + "," + .field2[0]' -r test.json | sort -n

@knittl I wanted to construct an array out of that, which apparently failed I think.

@WesternGun .hits.hits[].fields | [.field1[0] + "," + .field2[0]] creates a stream of arrays, e.g. ["1,FOO"]["2,FOO"]["3,FOO"]. If you want ["1,FOO","2,FOO","3,FOO"] you need [.hits.hits[].fields | .field1[0] + "," + .field2[0]] or map(…)

You're looking for something like this:
.hits.hits | map(.fields | .field1[0] + "," + .field2[0]) | sort[]

Online demo

Oh thanks, this is fast and exactly what I want. I didn't know I could strip the big array with sort[]; with sort only I got one big array. And it seems I have to stop one level above to start mapping. What a language. I don't know which operation is done to the whole, and which is to each element.

Do you have idea about the performance part, btw? jq sort vs bash sort

You can always do … | sort | .[] if that makes it easier to understand :)

@WesternGun The standalone sort utility is gonna be faster for big inputs.

@oguzismail yes I just checked sort materials, seems it's merge sorting and so on.

To sort by .fields.field1[0] use sort_by(.fields.field1[0]). But as you want to output the same values used as criteria, reduce beforehand using map, and just use sort on the result array:
jq -r '.hits.hits | map(.fields.field1[0]) | sort[]' file.json

Demo
Note that this performs string sorting as all first items of the .field1 arrays are actually strings (despite containing digits only, 11 would be sorted before 2). If you want numeric sorting (in the sense that two is smaller than eleven), convert the items into numbers first using tonumber. In this case, you could also drop the -r flag as JSON numbers don't have special encoding.
jq -r '.hits.hits | map(.fields.field1[0] | tonumber) | sort[]' file.json

Demo
As the sample data only has digit-only string items of equal lengths,  both approaches yield the same output:
111111113034864
111111113034877
111111113034894
111111113046053
111111113046124
:



I want a CSV file with both field1 and field2 separated by ,

With output items differing from the sorting criteria, I'd revert to using sort_by(.fields.field1[0]) as it gives you more freedom to mix and match, and have @csv construct the output, which also takes care of escaping special characters:
.hits.hits | sort_by(.fields.field1[0])[].fields
| [.field1[0], .field2[0]] | @csv

"111111113034864","FOO"
"111111113034877","FOO"
"111111113034894","FOO"
"111111113046053","FOO"
"111111113046124","FOO"

Demo

Thanks, I think map is the way. Sorry I have to accept the other one, as I want a CSV file with both field1 and field2 separated by ,; but thanks anyway

For the last edit, it adds several more levels of pipes and it seems long and confusing; and it at last still has quotations.
